# Display first or on top those records in the table by a preferred creteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Is there a way I could display first those records inside the table that has a 'branch' of 'BRANCH 1'? any ideas, help please? below is my snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dtable").DataTable( {
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1],[10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="dtable" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>BRANCH</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You mean to say branch1 should display first, than 2 and so on?

Comment: yes, those rows that has branch 1 on it should be displayed first.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use default sort of datatable more information can be found here:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Basically you just need  `"order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]`

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dtable").DataTable( {
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "dom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1],[10, 25, 50, "All"]],
      "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]]
        });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="dtable" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>BRANCH</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>NAME 1</td><td>BRANCH 1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: cool but how about all string like "branch one", "branch two"? and not "branch 1" or such like?

Comment: There must be something sortable it can not assume, or you can sort it at server side and send it sorted to datatable.